# How could i resolve warnings/errors related to apiservices which are no longer present in cluster

Tags: kubernetes

Kubernetes still tries already removed apiservice.

I have tried to deploy K10/Kasten and after uninstall I got stuck with errors refering to removed apiservices.

```
handler_proxy.go:150] error resolving kasten-io/aggregatedapis-svc: service "aggregatedapis-svc" not found
handler_proxy.go:106] no RequestInfo found in the context
controller.go:113] loading OpenAPI spec for "v1alpha1.apps.kio.kasten.io" failed with: Error, could not get list of group versions for APIService
controller.go:126] OpenAPI AggregationController: action for item v1alpha1.apps.kio.kasten.io: Rate Limited Requeue.
handler_proxy.go:150] error resolving kasten-io/aggregatedapis-svc: service "aggregatedapis-svc" not found
handler_proxy.go:106] no RequestInfo found in the context
```

when i doublecheck content of etcd, there is no reference to is anymore:

```
# ETCDCTL_API=3 etcdctl --endpoints=https://IP:2379 --cacert=/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/ca.crt --cert=/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/server.crt --key=/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/server.key  get / --prefix --keys-only | grep -i kasten
(no output)
```

neither any output from kubectl get for such apiservice

```
kubectl get apiservice v1alpha1.actions.kio.kasten.io
Error from server (NotFound): apiservices.apiregistration.k8s.io "v1alpha1.actions.kio.kasten.io" not found
```

is there any way how could I remove this warning/error (except of reinstall of whole cluster, which is not an option)